# Why can't i parse my R code in a Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: r, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I tried to use R in a Jupyter Notebook with VSCode, but I get the following Error:

```
summary(mtcars)
```

```
ERROR: Error in parse(text = x, srcfile = src): <text>:1:16: unerwartete Eingabe
1: summary(mtcars)
^
Error in parse(text = x, srcfile = src): <text>:1:16: unerwartete Eingabe
1: summary(mtcars)
                   ^
Traceback:
```

It seems like I there's a problem with the newline command, because I can execute multiple cells with one line of code each.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing the End of Line Command in VSCode from "\r\n" to "\n" did the trick...

Comment: God!! I wonder how you discover those bugs